# Where is std::this_thread for jthread?

Tags: c++, c++20

Can't figure out where is `std::this_thread` for `jthread`?

I have a function that theoretically makes a `jthread` sleep until a cancellation is requested:

```
template<typename Rep, typename Period>
void sleep_for(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& d, const std::stop_token& token)
{
    std::condition_variable cv;

    std::mutex mutex;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ mutex };

    std::stop_callback stop_wait{ token, [&cv]()
    {
        cv.notify_one(); }
    };

    cv.wait_for(lock, d, [&token]()
    {
        return token.stop_requested();
    });
}
```

How do I call it on `jthread`?

Theoretically the program below exits within 1 second:

```
int main()
{
    std::jthread t([]()
    {
        //where do I get `stop_token`?
        sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5), std::this_jthread::get_stop_token());
    });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    t.request_stop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_token, it's passed as argument to the worker function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The [jthread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) constructor accepts a function that takes a std::stop_token
> as its first argument, which will be passed in by the jthread from its
> internal stop_source.

Here is an example:

```
std::jthread t([](std::stop_token stop_token)
{
    while(!stop_token.stop_requested()) {
        //Process data...
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    }   
});
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
t.request_stop();
```

live on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7GYcYoj73).

Comment: This works, but it’s missing the point not to use the `jthread`’s internal `stop_source`.